# Symfony2 - How to add a ModelTransformer within FieldExtension?

Tags: php, forms, validation, symfony, doctrine-orm

## Goal

Custom Formelement written as an [Extension](https://gist.github.com/Clindbergh/acbff51e71d17df0054f) of the [(Doctrine) Entity Field](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html). The Element is rendered as a [Select2 Element with Tagging](http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/#tags). This allows to choose multiple items from a list or add a new value. If a new value is added, a new entity with the value as the property shall be created and associated to the underlying model of the formType.

## What works

I can successfully render the select2 Element with the available entities.

## Problem

The submitted value is a string containing the (unique) selected properties which currently causes a **validation error** (invalid value). It doesn't deliever the ID of the selected entities as the original field does, so I wrote a [generic DataTransformer](https://gist.github.com/Clindbergh/9247c1803ae28d6b375e) that should be able to deal with it. However I am **unable to [attach the transformer to the field as intended](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/data_transformers.html#using-the-transformer) from the context of the TypeExtension**. I would have to add the transformer inside my form. As another option I considered is to [suppress the validation Listener enitrely](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/dynamic_form_modification.html#suppressing-form-validation), but this would not only disable the validation of the enitre form, it wouldn't be helpful in correctly mapping the selected values to the enitities.

What's the best way to implement this functionality? As the [entity FieldType](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html) already offers most of the functionality, I would rather try to avoid to write a completly new fieldType.

### Update: Why I can't attach the transformer

One option would of course be to do it just the way [the cookbook entry](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/data_transformers.html#using-the-transformer) suggests, that is to attach the transformer whenever I use the field:

```
class MyFormType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        // ...

        $entityManager = $options['em'];
        $transformer = new ObjectListToStringTransformer($this->em,
                [
                    'class' => $options['class'],
                    'property' => $options['property'],
                    'delimiter' => ','
                ]
        );

        $builder->add(
            $builder->create('entityType', 'entity',
                array(
                    'select2' => true, /*Triggers the select2 template to be used*/
                    'multiple' => true,
                    'class' => 'Bundle:Entity',
                    'property' => 'name'
                )
            )->addModelTransformer($transformer)
        );
     }

     // ....
}
```

That could work. But this is not verbose and not typesafe. If I set `select2 => true` the Transformer *must* be added otherwise it will not validate. So I'd really like to have that done within my Extension. My first approach to achieve this was simply *wrong*, just the way the cookbook entry mentioned "how NOT to do it":

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    if ($options['select2']) {
        $builder->addModelTransformer(new ObjectListToStringTransformer($this->em,
                [
                    'class' => $options['class'],
                    'property' => $options['property'],
                    'delimiter' => ','
                ]
            )
        );
    }
    parent::buildForm($builder, $options);
}
```

This will add a transformer to the entire form, not only this field. AFAIK I can't do `create(...)->addModelTransformer($transformer)` as I probably could if it was a sub class (vertical inheritance) but not inside the extension (horizontal inheritance). Is there a way to add it after the field was already added? Or is there a way to achieve this by creating a subclass of the choice field?

Comment: Why don't you attach the transformer to the builder un the buildForm like http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/data_transformers.html#using-transformers-in-a-custom-field-type ?

Comment: @Qoop thanks, that's a good idea. I still get a validation error (see question), I wonder how to fix that.

Comment: @Qoop I remember why I didn't do it that way. The cookbook entry say's this is wrong:
`$builder->add('issue', 'text')
    ->addModelTransformer($transformer);`
as the Transformer would be applied to the entire form. How could I add the transformer to the field only from the context of the extension?

Comment: @Patrick I guess you solved your issue, so for someone else looking at this: to add the transformer only to a given field, and to have it done nicely, you could use what is mentioned here in the docs: http://symfony.com/doc/current/form/data_transformers.html#creating-a-reusable-issue-selector-field

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently the entity field itself has a registered `ModelTransformer` (or a `ViewTransformer`) which get called before my `ModelTransformer`. Since this always fails, my Transformer is never reached. To get around this, I changed `addModelTransformer` to `addViewTransformer`. While the code of my transformer wasn't working yet, the interaction with it does.